# Replace images of a HTML document with local Android resources, before loading the page in a WebView

Tags: android, html, webview

I know that for security reasons HTML standard doesn't allow anymore the loading of a local resource as image in a document.
Anyway I found that I have to copy the html files in the `android-asset` project folder if I want to load local pages in a WebView.

What if I want to use an hybrid approach? 
I would to get a HTML document from an uri, replace the value of the `src` attribute of a `img` HTML tag with a local path and then load the code in a WebView.

Having a html document like this:

```
<hmtl>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img src="http://URL-SITE/img/x.jpg">
    </body>
</hmtl>
```

- How can i replace `http://URL-SITE/img` with the path of a local image resource
  **before** the page is loaded by a WebView?
- I already tried putting the local image in the folder `android-asset` and changing the src value in `file:///android_asset/img/x.jpg` but it didn't work.

Comment: You can always embed the image data into the HTML itself with `<img src="data:image/png;base64,..." />` syntax

Comment: You have to get the source of the page first with a http client. Then parse the src attribute urls out and textually replace with the urls to files in assets. Your assets url is ok. But you have to place the pictures in assets directory. Not in the one you named. Finally give the adapted html source to the webview.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to download the images because I already have them and I don't want the user uses his mobile data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys, thanks for the comments.
The problem was that I used the command **loadData**

```
String html ="<html> <head></head> "
              +" <body>  <img src=\"file:///android_asset/img/x.jpg\"> "
              +"</body> </html>"; 

myWebView.loadData(html, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```

instead of

```
myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```